# Perform Unwind Segue Programatically in Unit Test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, segue

I am trying to unit test an unwind segue.

But it seems that in the test calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:` method doesn't perform an unwind segue while it does for other kinds of segues, e.g. Push and Modal segues.

Basically what I am trying to do is the following:

1. Get the view controller from storyboard.
2. Perform the unwind segue programmatically with this line of code:

   `[vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwind" sender:vc];`

   (I have tried to change the sender to `nil` and `vc.button` which is the triggering button for the unwind segue. But the test still failed.)
3. Check if the `seguePerformed` property in the view controller is set to YES with this line of code:

   `XCTAssertTrue(sut.seguePerfomed, @"should be true.");`

   In this view controller's `- prepareForSegue:` method, I am using the identifier of a segue to identify the unwind segue. If it is the unwind segue then set the view controller's seguePerformed property to YES.

I thought there was something wrong with my `performSegue` code.
However, if I copy this line `[vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwind" sender:vc];` into my view controller's `viewDidAppear` method to test it, and enter this view in an iPhone simulator. It does return to its previous view just after entering it.

Sorry that I forgot to mention that I also tried the following snippet:

```
- (void)testPerformingSegueShouldSetSeguePerform
{
    // given
    UINavigationController *nvVC = [sut.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nvVC"];

    [nvVC pushViewController:sut animated:NO];

    sut = (NTDSubViewController *)nvVC.topViewController;

    // when
    [sut performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwind" sender:sut.button];

    // then
    XCTAssertTrue(sut.seguePerfomed, @"should be true.");
}
```

Comment: I tried to assert on changes of the NavigationController's state. Strangely, neither the `viewControllers` count changed, nor did the `topViewController` change. Even in the simulator, it takes more than a single unwind call to see these changes in the destination VC right away. Don't know what's missing though.Any luck on your side?

Answer (score 0):

An unwind segue only makes sense in live context, because it has to do with instances, not classes. For example, if I start in View Controller A and I push View Controller B, then I can unwind, popping to View Controller A - not just any View Controller A, but the very instance that we started with.

But you are just pulling View Controller B out of the storyboard and trying to unwind. You can't because there is no View Controller A to unwind to. For this to work, you must do exactly what I just described: start with View Controller A, push to View Controller B, and now tell *that* View Controller B to unwind.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention I also tried to put it in the context. Please have a look at the code that I just added in the original post. Thanks. :D